# Thinkpad T470 "Critical low battery error"

Tags: battery, thinkpad

Last week, when I tried to use my thinkpad, it wouldn't wake up from sleep mode. I let it discharge its battery completely, hoping it would work after. The next day, I plugged it in, trying to turn it on, but it said "Critical low battery" and then it just turned off. My question is, would it be safe to try to charge it or would that damage the battery even more?

Answer (score 1):

You may have set the laptop for Hybrid Sleep and so (depending on design) may have kept the network card or some other device (USB Charging Outlet) alive. That most likely gave rise to the full discharge.

Will charging the battery from this discharged state harm it. No.

I would not make a habit fully discharging the battery (that can damage the battery if done enough times). Turn the computer fully OFF instead of indeterminate  suspends.

A T470 is a somewhat older ThinkPad (new in 2016), so if it will not start charging properly, the battery may need to be replaced. That is a normal occurrence for an older machine.

Try Dr. Battery on Amazon. The company puts new cells in the proper casing and warrants the battery. I have one in an X230 and it works great.

Comment: I tried to charge it but whenever I plug it in the power button just flashes 3 times

Comment: Your ThinkPad is not new (2016) so the battery may need to be replaced.